# Google Street View JS APIv3 retry request if street data found ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, oop, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

When I get panorama for marker within 50 meter max radius then sometimes it finds no panorama but if I'd set about 60+ meter radius then it would have worked.

So I'd like to auto make another request for street data with +10 meters radius and if nothing was found up to 100 meters total then stop completely.

I know how to loop it in procedural JS with for or while whatever, but I don't know OOP JS so I am not sure where/how to fire request again based on function response.

Basically code looks like

```
marker1.addListener('click', function(event) {
    popup1.open(map, marker1);
    sv.getPanorama({location: event.latLng, radius: 50}, processSVData);

});
```

...

```
function processSVData(data, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
            panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
            panorama.setPov({
                heading: 270,
                pitch: 0
            });
            panorama.setVisible(true);

        } else if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
            alert(status + " need to retry with radius +10 merters but how?");
        } else {
            alert(status + " cant do nothing about it bye");
        }
    }
```

Here's full example marker **B** has street view data at 50 meters when marker **A** does not. 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35dgzwqu/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is no conflict elsewhere in the program with the panorama queries calling too quickly (going over query limit), then a possible solution would be to use a function with a `timeout` to handle the query.

```
function getPanorama(args){
  setTimeout(function(){
    sv.getPanorama(args, function(data, status){processSVData(data, status, args); 
    //need to pass args to callback to properly increment
  }, query_limit_delay);
}
```

and in `processSVData`:

```
function processSVData(data, status, args){
  //code
  } else if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
    if(args.radius < 100){
      args.radius += 10; //increase radius by 10 meters
      getPanorama(args);
    }
  }
  //code
}
```

Basically, this 1) calls the `getPanorama` function. Once the delay (to not go over the query limit) has passed, it sends the returned data to the callback. If there are `ZERO_RESULTS`, the radius from the previous query is increased by 10, and the process repeats. However, if the data shows up, the data is handled and the loop exits.

One initiates a query by calling something like:

```
marker1.addListener('click', function(event) {
  popup1.open(map, marker1);
  getPanorama({location: event.latLng, radius: 50});
});
```

Good luck on your application!

Comment: Thats bit high tec for me how is timeout working exactly without set time?.

Comment: @RomanToasov `setTimeout` creates a `timeout` object that executes a function (passed as an argument) after a delay (also passed as an argument), starting when the function is called. Basically, it waits for a bit of time before doing something. This will not accidentally cause you to fire too many queries in a second, which would be detrimental for your program. It is very standard JS. This is a good learning opportunity.

Comment: I see your point now you added timeout feature to response to wait until next execution in a loop so google don't block script for rapid retry's. That actually made me think at first that i had to use timeout because of OOP specifics...

Comment: @bcdan Are you sure there's a query limit?  If so, do you know what it is?  I just repeated the query without waiting and it works so far.

Comment: @Keith I don't know the query limits off the top of my head but I do know that whether they kick in exactly or not is volatile. Basically, there's a chance the quota limit of 5 per second or whatever it is won't happen immediately and the queries continue. Having delays is robust programming that keeps the program from messing up just in case Google's query limits happen to work right.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a query limit to this API, I haven't reached it yet.  I implemented a recursive function.  Try something like:

```
marker1.addListener('click', function(event) {
    popup1.open(map, marker1);
    processSVData(event.latLng, 50); // first try 50 meters
});

function processSVData(loc,rad) {
    sv.getPanorama({location:loc, radius:rad}, function(data,status){
        if (status===google.maps.StreetViewStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
            processSVData(loc,rad+10); // increment by 10 meters
        } else if (status===google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
            // Success!
            panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
            panorama.setPov({
                heading: 270,
                pitch: 0
            });
            panorama.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            // Failure
            alert(status + " cant do nothing about it bye");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Be aware that if the listener is activated in quick succession, and the marker is far from available imagery, the requests can collect faster than they can be resolved.